# JavaScript toggling the order of object array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that I want to toggle the order by alphabetical order of a selected key.

```
var locationsOrdered = false;

function dynamicSort(property) {
  var sortOrder = 1;
  if (locationsOrdered) {
    if(property[0] === "-") {
      sortOrder = -1;
      property = property.substr(1);
    }
    locationsOrdered = false;
  } else {
    property = '-' + property;
    locationsOrdered = true;
  }

  return function (a,b) {
    var result = (a[property] < b[property]) ? -1 : (a[property] > b[property]) ? 1 : 0;
    return result * sortOrder;
  }
}


People.sort(dynamicSort('Surname'))

var People = [
    {Name: "Name", Surname: "Surname"},
    {Name:"AAA", Surname:"ZZZ"},
    {Name: "Name", Surname: "AAA"}
];
```

As you'll see from the above I have a function called `dynamicSort` which takes a given property but I'd like it to toggle the value to give it a `-` at the front if its been activated. So if you run `dynamicSort('Surname')` then the function should remember its been used before and prepend the `Surname` with `-`.

Essentialy I want to to reverse the order if its been used previously.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bangsi/y159f88v/)

Comment: You are toggling a boolean variable that you are using for the if/else.  Do you really need the '-' check?

Comment: But there is no `-Surname` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to save the state of the sort in a class object. I am sure there are easier ways to do this. But this works and may give you ideas how to better do it. Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1yy52fde/)

mysort is an instance of dynamicSort and keeps the current state for each of the properties you may be sorting on.

```
dynamicSort = (function(){
    function dynamicSort() {
    this.properties = {};
    };
    dynamicSort.prototype.sort = function(property){
    if (typeof this.properties[property] == "undefined"){
        // set the initial state
        this.properties[property] = 1;
    } else {
        // toggle the state
        this.properties[property] *= -1;
    }
    var sortOrder = this.properties[property];

    return function (a,b) {
        var result = (a[property] < b[property]) ? -1 : (a[property] > b[property]) ? 1 : 0;
        return result * sortOrder;
    }
}
    
    return dynamicSort;
})();   

var People = [
    {Name: "Name", Surname: "Surname"},
    {Name:"AAA", Surname:"ZZZ"},
    {Name: "Name", Surname: "AAA"}
];
mysort = new dynamicSort();

People.sort(mysort.sort('Surname'))
for (person of People){
    console.log(person.Name, person.Surname);
}
People.sort(mysort.sort('Surname'))
for (person of People){
    console.log(person.Name, person.Surname);
}
```

The first time it is sorted by Surname, it will output in ascending order:

> Name AAA
>
> Name Surname
>
> AAA ZZZ

The second time it is sorted by Surname, it will output in descending order:

> AAA ZZZ
>
> Name Surname
>
> Name AAA